# node.js edit variable from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello i have just started to learn node.js today and i am having a problem getting a variable from another file and editing it.

I'm trying to get the variable bots from server.js and edit it in bots.js.

server.js:

```
var bots = [
  { botID: '16f11103', userID: '12345' },
  { botID: '5657d5e9', userID: '54321' }
];

setInterval(() => { console.log(bots); }, 5000);

module.exports.bots = bots;
```

bots.js:

```
var request = require("../server.js");
var unique_id = '16f11103';

if (request.bots.some(e => e.botID === unique_id)) {
  request.bots = request.bots.filter(function(e) {
    return e.botID != unique_id;
  });
}
```

Comment: And what is your issue/error?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to create a function that sets the variable `bots`.

**Note:** Instead of using seperate variables and functions i suggest to use something like a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) to group all the functionality surrounding the bots.

**server.js**

```
var bots = [
  { botID: "16f11103", userID: "12345" },
  { botID: "5657d5e9", userID: "54321" },
];

var setBots = (newBots) => (bots = newBots);

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(bots);
}, 5000);

module.exports = { bots, setBots };
```

**bots.js**

```
var { bots, setBots } = require("./server.js");
var unique_id = "16f11103";

if (bots.some((e) => e.botID === unique_id)) {
  var newBots = bots.filter(function (e) {
    return e.botID != unique_id;
  });

  setBots(newBots);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because of how variables are modified in JavaScript (Think copy by reference vs value).

When you first export the `bots` variable in server.js:

```js
module.exports.bots = bots;
```

`module.exports.bots` is pointing to the `bots` variable by reference. If you modify the array directly like `module.exports.bots[0] = 1` it will be reflected in the original `bots` variable as well since the reference hasn't changed.

However, what you're doing is reassigning the module.exports.bots value completely. The [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a new array without modifying the original.

When you do:

```js
request.bots = request.bots.filter(function(e) {
    return e.botID != unique_id;
});
```

You're making it so that the `module.exports.bots` variable points to a new array and no longer points to the original `bots` array. That's why your console.log call is always printing the same array because the original bots variable is still pointing to that array and it was never modified.

If you don't want to modify the array directly you can try this.

server.js

```
var request = {};

request.bots = [
  { botID: '16f11103', userID: '12345' },
  { botID: '5657d5e9', userID: '54321' }
];

setInterval(() => { console.log(request.bots); }, 5000);

module.exports = request;
```

bots.js can now be kept exactly the same

```js
var request = require("../server.js");
var unique_id = '16f11103';

if (request.bots.some(e => e.botID === unique_id)) {
  request.bots = request.bots.filter(function(e) {
    return e.botID != unique_id;
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should do

```
    var bots = [
        { botID: '16f11103', userID: '12345' },
        { botID: '5657d5e9', userID: '54321' }
    ];

    setInterval(() => { console.log(bots); }, 5000);

    module.exports = bots;
```

instead of

```
module.exports.bots = bots;
```

You can also do

```
exports.bots = bots;
```

Then use Like this

```
var bots = require("./server.js");
var unique_id = '16f11103';

if (bots.some(e => e.botID === unique_id)) {
     bots = bots.filter(function(e) {
    return e.botID != unique_id;
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this code? Because this still won't work

Comment: the import should be var bots = require('./server.js')